# Probability of getting even heads in n biased coin tosses with different pi for each coin

Tags: probability

Lets say we have $n$ coins and probability of Coin $i$ to fall heads is $f(i)$ . Find the probability of getting an even number of heads when all the $n$ coins are tossed.

$f(i) = \frac {1} {2i + 3}$

Here $n$ is large, of the order of 1e5, so an efficient approach is required.

I tried to analyze the brute force case but that would be too much i.e. If I calculate for 2 success, 4, 6..., it might take years to run.

Then I thought of applying Linearity of Expectation somehow but couldn't come up with anything which could help. ​​

Comment: With a large number of flips the probability will approach $\frac 12$ regardless of the bias.

Comment: Why would one use Linearity of Expectation when expectations are not involved here?

Comment: @leonbloy you underestimate linearity of expectation's power

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
There is a simple recurrence equality which is provable by induction.

Deduce one from the fact that (denoting $H_n$ the $n$-th instance of your problem)
$$P(H_n) = p_n\cdot P(\neg H_{n-1})+ (1-p_n) \cdot P(H_{n-1})$$

This allows you to iteratively compute $P(H_n)$. Simplify this to a closed form.

Comment: Forgive me if I missed by a mile but is it (n + 5) / (2n + 3)? Thanks.

Comment: @KunwarSingh For $n=1$ the Formula is wrong. Can you find the starting Value and simplify the recurrence to a linear recurrence equation ($P(H_1):=P_1=?$ and $P_n=a(n) + b(n)P_{n-1}$)?

Comment: Got it, its (n + 3) / (2n + 3)!